# Delaying a jQuery remove class function when a form submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the class of 3 input elements in a single form when the button "submit" is clicked, but after 5 seconds of delay. I know I have to use the `setTimeout` function, but I don't know how to build my code, so it can work properly.

Here is the code that I wrote (it's very simple)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".contacts-submit").click(function() {
        jQuery('#input-1').removeClass('input--filled');
        jQuery('#input-2').removeClass('input--filled');
        jQuery('#input-3').removeClass('input--filled');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it using the `setTimeout` function :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".contacts-submit").click(function() {
      setTimeout(function() { // This anonymous function will be called
        jQuery('#input-1').removeClass('input--filled');
        jQuery('#input-2').removeClass('input--filled');
        jQuery('#input-3').removeClass('input--filled');
      }, 5000); // After 5000ms, (5 seconds)
  });
});
```

Comment: oh, WOW . I thought it is much harder -.-. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, you can accept my answer if it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap all your required functionality in `setTimeout`. There's also no need to repeat yourself, you can do it all in 1 selector.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery(".contacts-submit").click(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery('#input-1, #input-2, #input-3').removeClass('input--filled');
       },5000);

    });

});
```

Comment: oh, WOW . I thought it is much harder -.-. Thank you!